# on plus icon dynamic textbox is not getting generated in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

What I want is, I want to generate a new `input type = text` whenever a plus icon is getting clicked. SO I have written below code for the same.

```js
$('#dvDVRdata1 .add').on('click', function() {
  addDynamicTextbox();
});

function addDynamicTextbox() {
  //alert('icon clicked');
  var numItems = $('#dvDVRdata1').length;
  alert(numItems);
  if (numItems != 5) {
    var lastfieldsid = $('#dvDVRdata1 input').last().attr('id');
    if ($('#' + lastfieldsid).val() != "") {
      var id = parseInt(lastfieldsid.substr(13, lastfieldsid.length));
      var tr2 = $("#dvDVRdata1" + id + "");
      var tr = "<tr id='dvDVRdata1" + (id + 1) + "'><td><div class=''><div class=''><div class='' id='dvDVRdata1" + (id + 1) + "'><label>DVR Address</label><span><input type='text'  value='' name='nmDVRAddress" + "' id='txtDVRAddress" + (id + 1) + "'/></span></div></span></div></span></div></div><div class='minus'><i class='fa fa-times' aria-hidden='true'></i></div></td></tr>"
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-6" id="dvDVRdata1">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">DVR Address </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtDVRAddress1" runat="server" />
  </div>
  <div class="add">
    <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of problem in your code.

1. Use `slice(-1)` to get last character of id. It's remove your dependency using hardcode `substr(13,...` and you can use that value to  increase new generated id by +1 .
2. Check length for `input` using  `$('.form-group').find('input').length < 5` which check the length of input inside `form-group` class and user only able to add 5 inputs.
3. Finally don't forgot to append your generated element on `form-group` class using  `$('.form-group').append(tr);` .
4. I also add example to delete added `tr` using `minus` class.

Example:

```js
$('#dvDVRdata1 .add').on('click', function() {
  addDynamicTextbox();
});

function addDynamicTextbox() {
  //alert('icon clicked');
  var numItems = $('#dvDVRdata1').length;

  if ($('.form-group').find('input').length < 5) {
    var lastfieldsid = $('#dvDVRdata1 input').last().attr('id');
    if ($('#' + lastfieldsid).val() != "") {
      var id = parseInt(lastfieldsid.slice(-1));
      var tr2 = $("#dvDVRdata1" + id + "");
      var tr = "<tr id='dvDVRdata" + (id + 1) + "'><td><div class=''><div class=''><div class='' id='dvDVRdata" + (id + 1) + "'><label>DVR Address</label><span><input type='text'  value='' name='nmDVRAddress" + "' id='txtDVRAddress" + (id + 1) + "'/></span></div></span></div></span></div></div><div class='minus'><i class='fa fa-times' aria-hidden='true'>Remove</i></div></td></tr>";

    }
    $('#yourid').append(tr);
  } else {
    alert("warning........")
  }
}
$(document).on('click', 'div.minus', function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-6" id="dvDVRdata1">
  <div class="form-group" id="yourid">
    <label for="">DVR Address </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtDVRAddress1" runat="server" />
  </div>
  <div class="add">
    <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true">icon</i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: its directly prompting as `warning`

Comment: If input greater than 5 it's prompt warning. If you don't want that remove condition  ` if ($('.form-group').find('input').length < 5) {` from code.

Comment: No, for the first time only its prompting me as `warning`

Comment: yes its working, but one problem is that due to using class name, the textbox is getting generated everywhere. I want this to be precisely created for this div only

Comment: give form group some unique id and append using  id, don't use class :)

Comment: ?? any problem you face when use Id?

Comment: no when using ID it was ok. can u update the same with ID ?

Comment: See updated answer with id , hope it's help :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are going to add new input field in div#dvDVRdata1. You need to [append](https://api.jquery.com/append/) the HTMLcontent to that `div` as following:

`$('#dvDVRdata1').append(tr);`

Answer (score 0):

The thing is you need to `append` the element, which you did not do in the code in your question.

As for remove, you also have not done it in your question yet. Here's the example of add and remove.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.add').on('click', function () {
      addDynamicTextbox();
  });

  $('.del').click(function (e) {
      deleteDynamicTextbox(e);
  });
});

function addDynamicTextbox() {
    //alert('icon clicked');
    var numItems = $('.form-group .dvDVRdata').length;
    alert(numItems);
    if (numItems != 5) {
        var formGroup = $('.form-group');
        var elem = `<div class="dvDVRdata" id="dvDVRdata${numItems+1}">
                                        <label for="txtDVRAddress${numItems+1}">DVR Address </label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtDVRAddress${numItems+1}" runat="server" />
                                </div>`;
        formGroup.append(elem);
    }
}

function deleteDynamicTextbox() {
    //alert('icon clicked');
    var numItems = $('.form-group .dvDVRdata').length;
    alert(numItems);
    if (numItems > 1) {
        $(`#dvDVRdata${numItems}`).remove();
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-MV7K8+y+gLIBoVD59lQIYicR65iaqukzvf/nwasF0nqhPay5w/9lJmVM2hMDcnK1OnMGCdVK+iQrJ7lzPJQd1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/js/all.min.js" integrity="sha512-rpLlll167T5LJHwp0waJCh3ZRf7pO6IT1+LZOhAyP6phAirwchClbTZV3iqL3BMrVxIYRbzGTpli4rfxsCK6Vw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<div class="col-sm-6" id="dvDVRdata1">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="dvDVRdata" id="dvDVRdata1">
      <label for="">DVR Address </label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtDVRAddress1" />
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

  <div class="add">
     <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
  

  <div class="del">
     <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
```

Comment: but I want id as `dvDVRdata1`, `dvDVRdata2`, .....` And also I had minus icon for deleting the textbox

Comment: yes unique i understand. but if i click on plus then second textbox ID should be `dvDVRdata2`...

Comment: I am getting ids as `dvDVRdata${numItems}` in all the created textboxes. Also, minus sign is not coming if I want to delete the same textbox

Comment: You need to add the minus sign by yourself that you did not even state it in your question. Also you didn't have the function to remove the element in your question. Btw I have updated the code